# UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x0a'

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch

```
model_save_name = 'classifier.pt'
path = F"/content/gdrive/My Drive/Others/{model_save_name}"

model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path), strict = False)
```

*trying to load into model state_dict from path. Later the same model state_dict will be used for saving the checkpoint like `torch.save(model.state_dict(), path)`*

**Error Traceback:**

```
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-7cb7940c24e3> in <module>()
----> 1 model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path), strict = False)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py in load(f, map_location, pickle_module)
    356         f = open(f, 'rb')
    357     try:
--> 358         return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module)
    359     finally:
    360         if new_fd:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/serialization.py in _load(f, map_location, pickle_module)
    530             f.seek(0)
    531 
--> 532     magic_number = pickle_module.load(f)
    533     if magic_number != MAGIC_NUMBER:
    534         raise RuntimeError("Invalid magic number; corrupt file?")

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x0a'.
```

Answer (score -1):

Is the model saved using the same python version as the one trying to load. If not there have been some changes in pickle across versions. Also if this is not the case can you also post the torch.save() call you are making.

Comment: torch.save(model.state_dict(), path)
Is this fine or you want complete code block where torch.save is used?

Comment: Nope this is ok, lot of folks use torch.save for saving multiple attribute like optimizer state etc . The \x0a is new line so that is what pickle is getting but it's expected to be a dictionary. I will suggest you to try to pickle again and retry.